# Find probabilities given moment generating function.

Tags: statistical-inference

The moment generating function of $X$ is $$m(t)= \exp( -6t+32t^2)$$ Find

A. $\;\;P(-4<X<16)$

B. $\;\;P(-10<X<0)$

I have known that the first derivative for moment generating function is the expected value of $X.$

Comment: Maybe you should look at the form of $m(t)$. Do you see something familiar?

Comment: @Karl is right. It is more about knowing usual random variables and their respective moment generating function than a calculus problem. Unless you have seen the inverse Laplace transform.

Comment: I might have the idea that p(1)= -6 and p(2)=32 but I'm not even sure about that , if so how can I use it for my qaustion

Comment: examples of moment generating functions here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Examples

Comment: If that a normal continuous distribution , so the mean is -6 and the variance is 64 ? If so , I integrate the f(x) of the normal between the probability boundary?

Comment: and the important property suggested in the other comments to use: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Important_properties

Comment: @AhmadTalafha yes, once you know your probability distribution function or cumulative distribution function, the calculations of your probabilities should be standard.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Observe that the mgf of $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is $M_X(t)=\textrm{e}^{\mu t+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2t^2}$. So your random variable is $X\sim\mathcal{N}(-6,8^2)$.